# Sending questions(and answers) as a way to share code snippets

Tags: discussion

What do you think about this practice?

For example:

[A command to edit (another) file in the same directory without changing cwd](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/42941/a-command-to-edit-another-file-in-the-same-directory-without-changing-cwd)

There is also `gist.github.com` and I can share it in reddit, I guess. But somehow prefer here. What is the effect in terms of people reached?

Answer (score 3):

[Answering your own question is encouraged.](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

It allowed me to learn:

- custom command completion (thanks to you)
- the `find` command (thanks to matt)